# Undefined reference to 'cudaRegisterLinkedBinary' - linking error in CMake?

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, cuda

I'm running CentOS 7.8 via dual-boot on a 64-bit 2013 Mac with a GT 650M GPU. I'm using CMake 3.17, CUDA 10.0, and GCC 4.8.5. All CUDA samples have been tested and work fine, and I'm able to compile other standard C++ code perfectly.

I've reduced my full project to a simple test case as follows, where the CMakeLists file is:

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 3.8)

PROJECT(test LANGUAGES CUDA CXX C)

SET(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE ON)

MESSAGE(STATUS "Setting to Release mode")
SET(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE "Release")

# Set CUDA flags
set(CMAKE_CUDA_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CUDA_FLAGS} -arch=sm_30 -rdc=true")

# Set flags
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -g -Wall -ffast-math")
MESSAGE(STATUS "Setting g++ flags for Release configuration")
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -O3")   ## Optimize
SET(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} -s ")  ## Strip binary

ADD_SUBDIRECTORY( src )
```

In the /src folder I have another CMake file to gather the source files:

```
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES( ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR} )
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES( ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR} )

SET(test_SRCS
   rsmain.cu
   SGP4.cu
   SGP4.cuh
)

 function(my_add_executable TargetName)
   set(Files ${ARGV})
   list(REMOVE_AT Files 0)
   add_executable(${TargetName} ${Files})
   set_target_properties(${TargetName} PROPERTIES
                             RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY
                                 "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/build")
 endfunction()

my_add_executable(test ${test_SRCS})
INSTALL( TARGETS test DESTINATION bin)
```

As shown, there are three main source files - both SGP4.cu and SGP4.cuh are empty, while rsmain.cu is simply:

```
/// Main function
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    return 0;
}
```

When trying to build, I get the following output:

```
[me@localhost build]$ cmake3 ..
-- The CUDA compiler identification is NVIDIA 10.0.130
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.8.5
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.8.5
-- Check for working CUDA compiler: /usr/local/cuda-10.0/bin/nvcc
-- Check for working CUDA compiler: /usr/local/cuda-10.0/bin/nvcc - works
-- Detecting CUDA compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CUDA compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CUDA compile features
-- Detecting CUDA compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ - works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc - works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- No build configuration specified, defaulting to Release
-- Setting general compiler flags for detected compiler: gnu-g++
-- Setting g++ flags for Release configuration
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/me/Documents/test/build
[me@localhost build]$ make
/usr/bin/cmake3 -S/home/me/Documents/test -B/home/me/Documents/test/build --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 0
/usr/bin/cmake3 -E cmake_progress_start /home/me/Documents/test/build/CMakeFiles /home/me/Documents/test/build/CMakeFiles/progress.marks
make  -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 all
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/me/Documents/test/build'
make  -f src/CMakeFiles/test.dir/build.make src/CMakeFiles/test.dir/depend
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/me/Documents/test/build'
cd /home/me/Documents/test/build && /usr/bin/cmake3 -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /home/me/Documents/test /home/me/Documents/test/src /home/me/Documents/test/build /home/me/Documents/test/build/src /home/me/Documents/test/build/src/CMakeFiles/test.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
Scanning dependencies of target test
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/me/Documents/test/build'
make  -f src/CMakeFiles/test.dir/build.make src/CMakeFiles/test.dir/build
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/me/Documents/test/build'
[ 33%] Building CUDA object src/CMakeFiles/test.dir/rsmain.cu.o
cd /home/me/Documents/test/build/src && /usr/local/cuda-10.0/bin/nvcc   -I/home/me/Documents/test/src -I/home/me/Documents/test/build/src -I/home/me/Documents/test/build  -arch=sm_30 -rdc=true -O3 -DNDEBUG   -std=c++03 -x cu -c /home/me/Documents/test/src/rsmain.cu -o CMakeFiles/test.dir/rsmain.cu.o
[ 66%] Building CUDA object src/CMakeFiles/test.dir/SGP4.cu.o
cd /home/me/Documents/test/build/src && /usr/local/cuda-10.0/bin/nvcc   -I/home/me/Documents/test/src -I/home/me/Documents/test/build/src -I/home/me/Documents/test/build  -arch=sm_30 -rdc=true -O3 -DNDEBUG   -std=c++03 -x cu -c /home/me/Documents/test/src/SGP4.cu -o CMakeFiles/test.dir/SGP4.cu.o
[100%] Linking CUDA executable ../test
cd /home/me/Documents/test/build/src && /usr/bin/cmake3 -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/test.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/g++  -s  CMakeFiles/test.dir/rsmain.cu.o CMakeFiles/test.dir/SGP4.cu.o -o ../test  -lcudadevrt -lcudart_static  -L"/usr/local/cuda-10.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/stubs" -L"/usr/local/cuda-10.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib" -lcudadevrt -lcudart_static -lrt -lpthread -ldl
CMakeFiles/test.dir/rsmain.cu.o: In function `__sti____cudaRegisterAll()':
tmpxft_00004eed_00000000-5_rsmain.cudafe1.cpp:(.text.startup+0x25): undefined reference to `__cudaRegisterLinkedBinary_41_tmpxft_00004eed_00000000_6_rsmain_cpp1_ii_main'
CMakeFiles/test.dir/SGP4.cu.o: In function `__sti____cudaRegisterAll()':
tmpxft_00004f02_00000000-5_SGP4.cudafe1.cpp:(.text.startup+0x15): undefined reference to `__cudaRegisterLinkedBinary_39_tmpxft_00004f02_00000000_6_SGP4_cpp1_ii_71922fcb'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [test] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/me/Documents/test/build'
make[1]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/test.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/me/Documents/test/build'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Could anyone please explain what this 'cudaRegisterLinkedBinary' stuff is all about? I've tried a bunch of things in trying to solve it but nothing has worked so far. Is there an issue with any of the package versions? A problem in CMakeLists? Compatibility issues with CUDA and my hardware?

It's worth noting that the full code compiled and ran perfectly when I tested it on a HPC server (also running CentOS 7 and Cuda 10.0) - but on my personal PC it fails at the linking step. I've even confirmed that the .bashrc files are the same across both installations, but it hasn't fixed anything. I'm also currently able to compile NVIDIA's OptiX software (which also uses CUDA) without any problems.

Any advice would be appreciated. Please let me know if I missed any required details.

EDIT: Answer added below. Resolved.

Comment: The **first error** you get is `undefined reference to `main'`. It is better to fix errors from the start.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thanks, I forgot to leave the main function in tact :/

I've fixed the "undefined reference to `main'" error now, but still getting the CUDA linking issue (as with my original project).

Comment: Hint: For collect a function's arguments past the last named one, use `${ARGN}` construction. No needs to use list operations for `${ARGV}`. E.g.: `add_executable(${TargetName} ${ARGN})`

Comment: Would that fix the error? Or is it more for convenience?

Comment: This is just for convinience. This is unrelated to the problem.

Comment: Ah okay, thanks! It's weird because the full code compiles and runs perfectly when I tested it on a HPC server (also running CentOS 7 and Cuda 10.0) - but on my personal PC it just fails at the linking step. I've even confirmed that the .bashrc files are the same across both installations, but it hasn't fixed anything.

Answer (score 6):

Finally sorted this out. This was my main CMakeLists file:

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 3.8)

PROJECT(test LANGUAGES C CXX CUDA)
SET(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE "Release")

# Set CUDA flags
set(CMAKE_CUDA_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CUDA_FLAGS} -arch=sm_30 -rdc=true")

# Set flags
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -g -Wall -ffast-math -O3")
MESSAGE(STATUS "Setting g++ flags for Release configuration")
SET(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} -s")  ## Strip binary

ADD_SUBDIRECTORY( src )
```

And in the /src CMakeLists file, I had to make the change:

```
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES( ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR} )
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES( ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR} )

SET(test_SRCS
   rsmain.cu
   SGP4.cu
   SGP4.cuh
)

 function(my_add_executable TargetName)
   set(Files ${ARGV})
   list(REMOVE_AT Files 0)
   add_executable(${TargetName} ${Files})
   set_target_properties(${TargetName} PROPERTIES CUDA_RESOLVE_DEVICE_SYMBOLS ON
                             RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY
                                 "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/build")
 endfunction()

my_add_executable(test ${test_SRCS})
INSTALL( TARGETS test DESTINATION bin)
```

Setting CUDA_RESOLVE_DEVICE_SYMBOLS to ON is the change. In my main project, I also had to repeat this for every target involving any CUDA files. Everything compiles and runs perfectly now.